# Will there be any problems if I use audio datasets with different sampling rates for deep learning?

Tags: audio, deep-learning

I have two audio datasets for audio detection as train and test.
One is wav files with 8kHz sampling rates, 16bits, mono, 7secs.
The other one is wav files with 44.1kHz sampling rates, 16bits, mono, 10secs.
I put them in one folde and make 80% for train, 10% for validation, 10% for test.
But my friend said if I use datasets with different sampling rates it can cause wrong results.
It sounds like make sense to me, but I'm not sure why I must not use it(he doesn't know the reason neither).
So here are my questions.
1) using two audio datasets with different sampling rates cause any wrong results for audio detection?
2) If not so, I can use these datasets for train & evaluation? (because it's hard to find another datasets)

Comment: What will be the sampling rate of the audio on which you'd like to use the system (i.e. run prediction)?

Comment: I'd like to use 44.1kHz to make audio detection system. Actually i'm making baby crying detection system. 8kHz are baby sound, and 44.1kHz are glass, car, etc. But it's hard to find 44.1kHz baby sound so I just use 8kHz sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use whatever sampling rate that you are going to run on your "production system". Baby cries hardly require 44kHz, I'd say 8 kHz would work just fine. Even if the baby goes over 4 kHz, most of the power will be sitting below. You're not interested in understanding subtleties behind the cry, but just detect the cry.

It would make sense though to experiment a bit and download from the internet selection of crying babies at high fidelity and then analyse the spectrum. Downsample then to 8 kHz and see / hear how much difference it makes. I'd recommend Audacity, Python has some nice plotting libraries tool. Also, I made an open source online tool to help with ML in audio ([tool](http://audioexplorer.online), [docs](https://tracek.github.io/audio-explorer)). You might want to see how similar are audio features between e.g. baby cry and shattered glass.

Last but not least, reject the temptation of 80/10/10 split, likely you will overfit to the data. I'd advise to set aside at least 30% of data for testing, if possible 60%. If you feel "but I don't have that much data to spare for testing", then do one or more of the following:

- Collect more data
- Use algorithm that requires less data
- Use heuristic

It's all too easy to make ML system that does not generalise. Last tip: make sure that you don't get the same baby in different sets.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I really appreciate your help like advice and your open source :)
Setting at least 30% of data for testing quite interesting, I thought test set must be 10% or less. I'll try what you advise. Thank you once again.